# Is there a way to change cursor inside Wine for specific applications?

Tags: linux, wine

So my question would be that if it is possible to change an application's cursor whats running inside Wine/Lutris, to something that is more visible than the app's default?

As a background, I have a game what I run with Wine/Lutris, I need that game to learn some memory management and stuff on it, I spend a lot of time inside the game and I have problems following the cursor to the point where I need to search for it for 10 seconds, because its just small. On Windows I used to use YoloMouse. The game is Guild Wars 2.